# How to set some text in a EditText from java file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I am setting some text on edit text, it become non editable.

Example:

```
EditText ET;
ET=findViewById(R.id.e_textid);
String S="stringWillComeFromDatabase";
ET.setText(S);
```

Comment: It should not be this way, try with adding `ET.setEnabled(true);` after `setText`.
Also see if it's editable in your xml file

Comment: Thank you. The problem occured as I used android:textIsSelectable="true"  in the .xml file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code something like that:

`EditText ET;`

`ET= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_textid);`

`String S="stringWillComeFromDatabase";`

`ETsetEnabled(true);`

`ET.setText(S);`

If you want to use copy value in the EditText then use:

`editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);`

> Make sure you have enabled that with your EditText

`android:editable="true"`

`android:focusable="true"`

`android:clickable="true"`

Default EditText editable is true. You can do vice versa to change non editable EditText just pass false instead of true.

I hope it will help you!!!:)

Comment: Thank you. The problem occured as I used android: textIsSelectable="true" inside the <EditText />  in  .xml file